# Intuition. Cauchy criteron for Riemann integrability (Spivak pp 239, S. Abbott pp 189 thm 7.2.8)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, intuition

> **1.** Why $\inf U(f,P') \le U(f, P)$ and $\sup L(f, P') \ge L(f,P) $?
>   I tried to research but I can't find where Spivak defined it $P'$?
>
> **2.** Why are there two partitions P', P''? Not the same? P' is for the upper sum and P'' for the lower sum?
>   I see the proof later defines $P = P' \cap P''$? Why not start with this one partition?
>
> **3.** Intuition please on this result? I don't understand how an equality $\sup L(f,P) = \inf U(f,P)$ is equivalent to a strict inequality. I know the proof of theorem 1.2.6:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please apprise me if this theorem has a name. Can revise title.

Comment: 1. $\inf U(f, P')$ is an infinium carried over all possible partitions $P'$. Perhaps it would have been more clear if we had written $\inf_{P'} (f, P')$. 2. Yet again $P',P''$ are just dummy variables over which suprmums and infinums are taken. 3. Is just the definition of integrability which could be interpreted as meaning that limits of approximations of step functions from below and above should be equal if area is to make sense --- I only answer here in brief to try and resolve the issue of definitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The book is just being sloppy there. $P'$ simply ranges over all possible partitions in the infimum and supremem. In other words, when it says $\inf \{ U(f,P') \}$, it means $$
     \inf \left\{ U(f,P') \,|\, \text{$P'$ is a partition} \right\} \text{,}
   $$
   and the same goes for the supremem.
2. Because $\inf \{ L(f,P) \} = \sup \{ L(f,P) \}$ doesn't guarantee (or at least not *obviously* guarantee) that there's a *single* paritition $P$ for which $$
     U(f,P) - L(f,P) < \epsilon \text{.}
   $$
   It only telly you that there is *some* paritition (say $P'$) for which $U(f,P')$ is closer to the supremem than $\epsilon/2$ (because if there weren't, it wouldn't be a supremem), and that simiarly there is some $P''$ for which $L(f,P'')$ is closer than $\epsilon/2$ to the infimum. Since the infimum and the supremem are the same, it follows that $U(f,P') - L(f,P'') < \epsilon$. Now that you have that, you can go looking for a *single* partition $P$ for which this holds. Which you do by looking for a $P$ which is finer than *both* $P'$ and $P''$, and which thus *increses* the lower bound and *decreases* the upper bound. Thus, for this single $P$, the relationship still holds, and voilá, you got your proof.
3. The result simpyl tells you that yes, integrable really just means that if you choose a fine enough partition, the lower bound and the upper bound are arbitrarily close together. In other words, both the lower and the upper bound converge to the same number as the partition gets finer and finer *exactly if* the function is integrable.